# How can I reinstall basically everything on an LG G2

Tags: twrp, lg

I don't know what happened, to be honest, it was a couple of years ago.
I rooted my LG D802 with TWRP. Because I was young and dumb and had no idea what I was doing, I decided to wipe the whole storage. Literally nothing is left except TWRP 2.7.0

My questions might sound dumb, maybe, i dont know, but here goes:
First off: Where do i get the files? Literally anything that is remotely related to an operating system is entirely gone. So i would literally have to install everything down to the metal. I remember trying to just flash a ROM back then, but that hasnt helped. Recently, i came to the conclusion, that it might be the missing kernel? Maybe im talking absolute nonsense, but i still havent really looked into that matter and im just trying to get my old phone back as a backup phone. 
What would I need to get this working again? Is it possible at all? I have the Drivers and ADB Tools installed, but none of that has had an effect, flashing anything just fails miserably.